# How Could I Write a helper function which is query from mongodb , and then can call this func for any ejs template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, ejs

I want to write a function with one param `id` for this mongo to pass to my `home.ejs`.

Example with this query:

`db.getCollection('users').find('5da85558886aee13e4e7f044', {image: 1})`

Example I have a route.

## routes/users.js

```
var User = require("../models/user");
var db = require("../secure/db");
var middleware = require("../middlewares/middleware");
 //...
router.get("/home", middleware.isAllowed, function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('home',{
  title: "Project",
  userList: userList,
  getUserimage: getUserimage(??)//trying here 
 })

});
```

so in `home.ejs` or any `file.ejs`
I can call like `getUserimage('5da85558886aee13e4e7f044')` inside loop of list of `ids`

## views/home.ejs

```
 <% layout('layout/layout') %>
 //more code
 <% for(var i=0; i < userList.length; i++){ %>
    <div>
    <img src ="<%=getUserimage(userList[i].id)%>" > <%=userList[i].name%> 
    </div>
 <% } %>
 //more code
```

Here is my updated helper

```
var User = require("../models/user");
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

module.exports.getUserImage = async function getUserImage(id) {
  let result = await  User.find(ObjectId(id), {image: 1, _id: 0}).lean();
   console.log(result[0].image);
    return result[0].image; //or whatever you wanna return 
  };
```

When I `console.log` it is gave me the correct result. but when I call in view.ejs like this `<%=getUserImage("5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e")%>`   file it give me `[object Promise]`

Answer (score 2):

Create a file , we name it helper.js.

```
module.exports.getUserimage = async function(id){

    //do something
    //replace this with your own code but use the await
    let result = await collection.findOne(query);
    return result; //or whatever you wanna return 


}
```

Then inside app.js you can do this

```
const helper = require("helper");

app.locals.getUserimage = helper.getUserimage
```

Then you can call it inside your .ejs template like the way you are doing.

```
 <% layout('layout/layout') %>
 //more code
 <% for(var i=0; i < userList.length; i++){ %>
    <div>
    <img src ="<%= getUserimage(userList[i].id)%>" > <%=userList[i].name%> 
    </div>
 <% } %>
 //more code
```

app.locals properties persist throughout the life of the application. Provide the complete path to the helper.js file. I have assumed that is in the same directory as the app.js file.

Comment: can I create a separate file? and how to include , could please guide me more?

Comment: I have made a edit . This will do it the way you want it.

Comment: I was the problem of using getUserimage query from mongodb
example getUserimage(id){
User.find(Object(id), {image: 1. _id:0 })}, how we could pass async function in that case.

Comment: Made another edit. But why don't you just return an array of string that contain the path to to the userimage, just like you are sending the user list . Because in terms of performance there is no difference. Essentially calling the method from the template still means you are doing all the work on the server end.

Comment: I see this `[object Promise]` when call in template ejs, can please help to check my update trying code.